# AWS EC2 AMI export

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a ec2 instant which is our web server.
I make its AMI , Now i want to export that AMI in my local server which is in a data center.
How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot download an AMI via any supported method. The exception is if you originally created the VM on your own hardware and then imported this environment into AWS.